# Setting the color of the highlighted item in list when it has no input focus by means of CMFCVisualManager Class

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, look-and-feel, clistctrl

**Brief introduction:**
In order to set custom look for control elements of my Win application I use `CMFCVVisualManagerOffice2007` which has the set of mapping: color->element of control, and implements drawing of controls, based on that mapping, this allows to give consistent look to the application.
I override some mappings, by providing colors I need, in order to organize my own palette.

**Problem description:**
I need to change the color of the item selected in the list, when list has no input color.
When the list has input focus - it is alright,selected element is highlighted with the blue, clearly visible color, but when focus is lost - it is highlighted with gray which doesn`t fit to the palette of my application.

Among mappings I can`t find one for the case when element of the list, with always select style, is selected, but that list has no input focus.
I am aware that I can implement my own draw for that list and set color I need for the situation when element is highlighted and hasn`t got the input focus.
But I want to find the solution based on the configuration of palette.

**Question:**
What is the name of palette element what represents color for highlight of selected element in the list which has no focus?

Comment: Could you add an image to illustrate your question?